# Example IModelBinderProvider implementation for ModelBinder constructor injection in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, modelbinders

I need to wire my custom ModelBinder up to my DI container in MVC 3, but I can't get it working.

So. This is what I have:
A ModelBinder with a constructor injected service.

```
public class ProductModelBinder : IModelBinder{
  public ProductModelBinder(IProductService productService){/*sets field*/}
  // the rest don't matter. It works.
}
```

My binder works fine if I add it like this:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Product),
     new ProductModelBinder(IoC.Resolve<IProductService>()));
```

But that is the old way of doing it, and I don't want that.

What I need is help on how to hook that modelbinder up to the IDependencyResolver I've registered.

According to Brad Wilson the secret is using a IModelBinderProvider implementation, but its very unclear as to how to wire that up. ([in this post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt9-model-binders.html))

Does anyone have an example?

Comment: IModelBinderProvider would be your own implementation. It just so happens I wrote a blog post about just this thing http://buildstarted.com/2010/12/02/modelbinderproviders-automatic-binding-your-models-is-easy-as-pie/ Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, that's working well. I just replace the CreateInstance()stuff with                     var instance = (IModelBinder) DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(type);
Thanks!

.

Comment: I still think it should be possible to make a more clean implementation using generics. I need to sleep on that, I think ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced the same situation when coding my MVC 3 app. I ended up with something like this:

```
public class ModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    private static Type IfSubClassOrSame(Type subClass, Type baseClass, Type binder)
    {
        if (subClass == baseClass || subClass.IsSubclassOf(baseClass))
            return binder;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public IModelBinder GetBinder(Type modelType)
    {
        var binderType = 
            IfSubClassOrSame(modelType, typeof(xCommand), typeof(xCommandBinder)) ??
            IfSubClassOrSame(modelType, typeof(yCommand), typeof(yCommandBinder)) ?? null;

        return binderType != null ? (IModelBinder) IoC.Resolve(binderType) : null;
    }
}
```

Then I registered this in my IoC container (Unity in my case):

```
_container.RegisterType<IModelBinderProvider, ModelBinderProvider>("ModelBinderProvider", singleton());
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 6):

You need to write your own `IModelBinderProvider` and register it with the `ModelBinderProviders.BinderProviders` collection:

```
public class YourModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider {
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(Type modelType) {
         if(modelType == typeof(Product)) {
             return new ProductModelBinder(...);
         }
         return null;
    }
}
```

In Global.asax:

```
ModelBinderProviders.BinderProviders.Add(new YourModelBinderProvider());
```

Comment: Is it better to register the IModelBinderProvider in IoC so that MVC automatically requests it or register it explicitly using BinderProviders.Add(...) ? Also, if we are trying to handle multiple binders (based on the model type), is there a pattern you would recommend?

Comment: You could do it either way. I guess I just prefer the traditional approach.

Comment: How are you trying to handle multiple binders? The firs binder provider that returns a non-null binder wins. So it's just a matter of ordering things appropriately.

Comment: Have a look at my answer below... I am currently using this is a development project.